Adding custom tags to an AVI format file
I converted mov file to AVI file, and I need it to have similar settings to some other video I have.
I saw that it has tags that are not the standard AVI tags. I tried to use ffmeg and add it to my converted file, but it doesn't add these tags.
Any idea how to add it anyway in my Mac? (I suppose it should be possible somehow because the other video does have that tags)
Thank you!
